# Astyle formatting for vscode: extension doesn't have a config file

Tags: visual-studio-code, astyle

I am trying to get https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chiehyu.vscode-astyle to work (if anyone has a different extension or settings I can use, I am all ears).

I cannot find a config file for it, even though the page implies that there are config parameters. I cannot find anywhere where I can, for example, specify the path of the astylerc file. Typing 'astyle' into the command tool bar says that there are no commands matching, even though I have installed the extension and restarted my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Of course, I figured it out immediately after asking the question.

Settings (the gear in the bottom right) -> astyle configuration.